# Binomial distribution - the smallest suitable number

Tags: binomial-distribution

Each year, a detailed study is conducted on a random sample of 36 Lorenz birdwing butterflies in Town A. A Lorenz birdwing butterfly is considered to be very large if its wingspan is greater than 17.5 cm. The probability that the wingspan of any Lorenz birdwing butterfly in Town A is greater than 17.5 cm is 0.0527, correct to four decimal places. For random samples of 36 Lorenz birdwing butterflies in Town A,  is the random variable that represents the number of butterflies that are very large.

The probability that  or more butterflies, in a random sample of 36 Lorenz birdwing butterflies from Town A, are very large is less than 1%. Find the smallest value of , where  is an integer.

Is it correct to think it as to find the smallest integer  such that
36**C** * 0.0527^k * (1-0.0527)^36-K < 1% ? If so, how should I calculate it?

Note: (36**C** as in choose  from 36 with replacement)

Comment: No, you want $k$ **or more** butterflies, not $k$ butterflies.

Comment: Yep, good point. The way I was doing only considered k butterflies. How would I specify k or more butterflies though?